# como dar formato a un campo con jquery

Tags: jquery, formato

`introducir el código aquí`  Como puedo dar formato para que de muestre de  esta manera "000.000.000,00"  para los campos "#iva" y "#total"

```
var montobase;
var iva;
montobase=$("#precio").val()*$("#cantidad").val();
iva=montobase*0.12;
$("#iva").val(iva);
$("#total").val(montobase-iva);
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar javascript utilizando el objeto [Intl.NumberFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat)

```
ivaFormateado =  new Intl.NumberFormat('es-ES', { style: 'currency', currency: 'EUR' 
          }).format(iva);
    
totalFormateado=  new Intl.NumberFormat('es-ES', { style: 'currency', currency: 'EUR' 
          }).format(total);
```